# Where is the offline documentation for GetLastError in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msdn, help-viewer

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Professional with the Help Viewer. I've downloaded the following documentation sets for offline use using the Manage Content tab:

- .NET Framework 4.5 (includes 4.5.2)
- Visual Studio 2013: Fundamentals
- Visual Studio 2013: Visual C++
- API Reference for Windows Store apps
- Windows Desktop App Development
- Windows Debugging

However the function `GetLastError` doesn't show up in the index. If I follow a link to its documentation, e.g., from the page for `CreateWindow` (which *is* in the index), it fetches an online copy with a helpful message at the top:

> You are viewing online content. The topic is not available on your computer, but it is available in one or more books

This helpful message includes a link to the Manage Content tab, presumably so you can download one of those books, but no indication of which books the page might be stored in!

How do I find out what I need to download?

(I am trying to avoid doing this by trial and error.)

Comment: seems MS messed up with the desktop documentation. I also found CreateFont(), SetTextColor(), and other bunch of GDI function are missing from VS 2013 documentation

Comment: The "offline" docs are a total mess, the API reference for Store apps exhibits the same behavior e.g. for class GattCharacteristics

Comment: I filed a Connect bug for this, as it still affects VS2015 even when you install every doc available: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3097674